# RedirectToAction on [HttpPost] returning "resource not found" error

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

I have a fairly simple project with is using ninject with asp mvc 4 and entity framework. 
I have added an edit and create ActionResult based on the view with no problems. However the **delete ActionResult is not working.**

The view is a IEnumrable based on the entity, with a simple ActionLink

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete_Client", new { item.ClientId })
```

The controller is also very simple.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete_Client(int id)
    {
        Client deleteClient = repository.DeleteClient(id);

        if (deleteClient != null)
        {
            TempData["message"] = string.Format("{0} was deleted.", deleteClient.Name);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Admin_Client_List");
    }
```

This interacts with the model through the Iinterface

```
 Client DeleteClient(int id);
```

and in the Entity framework

```
 public Client DeleteClient(int id)
    {
        Client dbEntry = context.Clients.Find(id);
        if (dbEntry != null)
        {
            context.Clients.Remove(dbEntry);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        return dbEntry;
    }
```

The error is

> **The resource cannot be found.**

This is very confusing because i feel like i am not understanding a very fundamental principle of the framework. As i understand it, that means that there is no corresponding ActionResult for the client controller. But there is. The tutorial is am working through suggested that a delete action should be **idempotent** and therefore only contain a **[HttpPost]** .

The Uri looks like this

```
/Client/Delete_Client?ClientId=12
```

I thought that maybe it would need to look like this

```
/Client/Delete_Client/12
```

However that does not work.

---

**Updated request for Admin_Client_List.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Domain.Entities.Client>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Client List";
    ViewBag.Icon = "entypo-layout";
    ViewBag.ClientActive = "active";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}

<a href="@Url.Action("Create_Client","Client")" class="btn btn-primary">Create a new Client</a>
<div class="row">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-sm-3">

            <div class="tile-progress tile-blue">

                <div class="tile-header">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Client_Details", "Client", new { id =item.ClientId})">
                        <h3>@item.Name <i class="entypo-right-open-big"></i> <span class="badge badge-secondary pull-right">7</span></h3>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="tile-progressbar">
                    <span data-fill="78%" style="width: 78%;"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="tile-footer">
                    <h4>
                        <span class="pct-counter">78</span>% increase
                    </h4>

                    <span>@item.Description</span>

                </div>

                <div class="tile-header">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Edit_Client", "Client", new { id = item.ClientId})" type="button" class="btn btn-blue btn-icon icon-left">
                        <i class="entypo-pencil"></i> Edit
                    </a>

                    @*<a href="javascript:$('#modal-6').modal('show', {backdrop: 'statuc'});" class="btn btn-default">Show Me</a>*@

                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete_Client", new { id = item.ClientId }) 

                    @*<a href="@Url.Action("Delete_Client", "Client", new { item.ClientId })" class="btn btn-red btn-icon pull-right">Delete <i class="entypo-cancel"></i></a>*@
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Is your action method in the same controller?

Comment: Hey Reddy. Yeah it is. Along with the edit and create. They are all in the ClientController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete_Client", null, new { id = item.ClientId })
```

and you must delete the [HttpPost], this is a GET request

Comment: Hey theLaw. Thanks this did work. In the tutorial i am going through they suggest that this ActionResult should have the filter [HttpPost] "This action method should support only POST requests, because deleting objects is not an idempotent operation. As we will explain in Chapter 14, browsers and caches are free to make GET requests without the user’s explicit consent, so we must be careful to avoid making changes as a consequence of GET requests." . Do you happen to know why this does work with the filter?. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete_Client", new { id = item.ClientId }) 


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete_Client(int id)
{
    Client deleteClient = repository.DeleteClient(id);

    if (deleteClient != null)
    {
        TempData["message"] = string.Format("{0} was deleted.", deleteClient.Name);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Admin_Client_List");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bappi Datta. Looksing at that code it should work. The uri is Client/Admin_Client_List/{id} which should work.

Comment: can you please give the code of Admin_Client_List.

If it is like that: Admin_Client_List(int id), then you can use this :

return RedirectToAction("Admin_Client_List", new { id = id });

Comment: if you want Client/Admin_Client_List/{id}  to work you need to pass values on `RedirectToAction`. something like 
`return RedirectToAction("Admin_Client_List", new {id = id});`

currently I am not using VS so don't mind the typo.

Comment: Nope that doesnt work. I think this has to do with ninject or EF .. i think i have done something wrong in the model.

Comment: Hey. I updated the controller and removed the [HttpPost] Filter. And it worked with the changes. I dont want to go down a rabbit hole but do you perhaps know why it works without the [HttpPost] ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change your code

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete_Client", new { item.ClientId })
```

to

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete_Client", new { id = item.ClientId })
```

Comment: I thought that might actually be the problem, I dont know if this has something to do with the routing engine. It is currently default. Its really odd though because the create / edit and works find , its just this delete.